# Xamarin Android Fragment TextView SetText

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have created a Fragement and in the fragment i have placed TextView. I want to update Text of TextView. I have used below code but it is not working.

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup)inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.homefragmentlayout, null);

        var fragmentView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.homefragmentlayout, null);

        System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        timer.Interval = 1000; 
        timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
        timer.Enabled = true;
        timer.Start ();

        DateTime oldDate = new DateTime(2015, 12, 25);
        DateTime newDate = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan timeSpan = oldDate - newDate;

        var content = new SpannableString (timeSpan.Seconds.ToString("00"));
        TextView txtSeconds = fragmentView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtSeconds);
        txtSeconds.SetText(content, TextView.BufferType.Spannable);

        return root;
    }
```

Please let me know if I am missing anyting.

Comment: What is "not working"? Compiler error? Exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use same View object which is return from `OnCreateView` method for accessing View's from current Fragment Layout.

Currently returning `root` from method but using `fragmentView` for accessing and updating text in `TextView`.

So just change return statement to :

```
return fragmentView;
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, worked like a charm. I was trying different approach since 6 hours.